# Merge field watermark - Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, mergefield

I want to add a conditional Watermark in a word document using merge field. Is there any way to accomplish this? Is there any way to use merge field condition like below to add "DRAFT" watermark? or any other way to use a condition to make a watermark visible on the document? I am using Microsoft Word 2013. Thanks in advance for your help guys.

```
{ IF"{MERGEFIELD SampleField}"="Yes" "DRAFT" "" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, with the caveat that you can't use Word's built-in Insert/Watermark functionality. An "If" conditional can work only with textual content. Word's built-in Watermarks are "WordArt" - which places an object in the document.

But you can use the Text Box drawing tool (as in Insert/Text Box/Draw Text box) to create the "container" for the watermark text in the document Header. It can be positioned anywhere on the page; make sure you set the text wrap formatting to "Behind text".

Insert the If field into that, with the nested mergefield and conditional statement. You need to type the watermark text and format it the way you want to have it.

Answer (score -1):

The correct format:
{ IF { MERGEFIELD PrintCopy = 1 "ORIGINAL" "COPY" }}

Add spaces before and after the equal sign
Make sure the entire row (text above) is highlighted in grey when you click on it in the word document, otherwise it is only text once merged.